# Make call Error Listener - Android

Tags: android, listener, phone-call

I have functionalities like make call, receive call etc.
How can I handle the error scenarios while making a call and at the other end,  the user is not reachable or the  SIM card does not exist, etc.

Is there any listener available for that?

**Edit**

1. How can I know the 2nd user is reachable ?
2. Failed to call because of enough account balance

Comment: What errors do you get? Why can't you try-catch any errors?

Comment: @cricket_007: I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TelephonyManager class to know the status of the user.

CALL_STATE_IDLE: This means user is idle and no Activity

CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: This means  At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.

CALL_STATE_RINGING: This means A new call arrived and is ringing or waiting. In the latter case, another call is already active.

Refer this Example : [Call listener](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-phonestatelistener-phone-call-broadcast-receiver-tutorial)